# C++ suppress assertions in debug build

Tags: c++, exception, wxwidgets, assertion, suppress

I have my wxWidgets client/server application and faced a complicated bug inside wxWidgets network stuff. It's a long story, let's skip it here.

wxWidgets code uses assertion, so I can't catch it as if it was an exception.

**Can I suppress assertions while still compiling in debug mode?**

Every time assertion happens, there is wxWidget's assertion info window appears, so user needs to press "Continue" or "Abort" button. If I can't catch it (assertion is not an exception), I'd like to suppress it.

Comment: It was wrong to close this question because wxWidgets assertions (`wxASSERT()`, `wxCHECK()`, ...) are quite different from the standard `assert()` macro, even if they are both affected by `NDEBUG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about standard [`assert` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), you can turn it off by defining `NDEBUG` macro.

> If NDEBUG is defined as a macro name at the point in the source code
>   where `<cassert>` is included, then `assert` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but unfortunately did not solved my problem with wxWidgets; after suppressed assertion, GUI stops to repaint how it should, and once it even took down openbox. I'll try to find another lib for networking.